# Guru Paramparas of Shad Darshanas other than Vedanta

Tags: history, tradition, purva-mimamsa, shad-darshana, nyaya

Are there any surviving Guru Paramparas of Purva Mimansa/ Vaisheshikha/ Nyaya/ Sankhya /Yoga?

Comment: Are you asking for everyone or are you asking for anyone?

Comment: Yes, I am asking about all of them (separately).